# Gettext not working through php-cli, but works in php-apache

Tags: php, apache, internationalization, locale, gettext

The code i run looks as the following:

```
...
$this->locale = da_DK;
...
putenv("LC_ALL=".$this->locale);
putenv('LANG='.$this->locale);
$res = setlocale(LC_ALL, $this->locale);
if($res != $this->locale){
    throw new Exception("The language could not be set.");
}
bindtextdomain("domain", "./locale");
textdomain("domain");

 echo setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 0 );
 echo ' ';
 echo __('description');
```

Result running it through apache2 is:

```
da_DK Beskrivelse
```

Which is as we want.

Running it throgh cli:

```
da_DK Description
```

Which would have been correct if we had used english. The 'd' is upper case in the english translation and the lower case in the source (From out of context it seems a bit weird)

So gettext works as it can translate the string, but somehow it disregards that i changed locale in the script and chose the .po file from the english directory.

In case you wonder why i need locales on a cli script: The script is used to emails out invoices.

I use: 
Ubuntu 12.10, PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1, apache 2.2.22, and gettext  0.18.1.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to reset the environment Variable LANGUAGE:

putenv("LANGUAGE=");

Took me a while to find out.

Comment: Wow, who would have known :) Thanks. Any explanation behind this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the bindtextdomain() points the same resource file from php-cli and php-apache. I suggest,

1. echo the return value of the bindtextdomain() and see them.
2. try to replace "./locale" to absolute path (e.g. "/var/www/yourproject/locale") and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

1. Returns same path
2. Using absolute paths did not help.

Comment: OK. So it was not the cause I initially suspected. How about resource files and the locale folder's permission? Are they readable both from the Unix user which runs php-cli and Apache? You may temporarily give full permissions like 777 to them.

Comment: Sry for the long response time. I tried it, but it didn't help. Sadly we might go with some kind of curl solution to load the script through apache. Though a real reason for this issue could be nice :) Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much this is relevant or not but …

I just found a solution to the **opposite** problem: Gettext not working through **php-apache**, but working in **php-cli**.

Also concerned, **strftime** localization not working through **php-apache** but working in **php-cli** (on a Linux Debian buster system).

LANGUAGE environment variable did not help as I do not have such environment variable.

Strangely, I just disabled the **perl** module in Apache and the problem disappeared.

So maybe some bugs in any Apache module could trigger this kind of problem…

Comment: I experienced the exact same problem as you described (works in cli, not through apache) and indeed, as soon as I disabled the perl module, it worked! But WHY?

Comment: still known why need to disable perl module?? PHP 8.2 with Apache/2.4.54 (Unix). Still need to disable #LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so in order to get i18n gettext php working... WHY!!??