# PHP gettext translate in wrong language when running from shell

Tags: php, shell, cron, gettext

I have a complete PHP app, with MySQL.

All strings are using gettext, and I have 2 translations, Spanish and English.

Original strings are written in Spanish.

it is working perfect, but, when I run a cron job, to send a report email, it is sent using English, when it should send in spanish.

The problem isn't related to the mail code, since it works ok when I run the cron file on the browser, plus, my email system first save it to the DB then it sends them, and the message is already stored in English on the DB.

So, I know my problem is the cron file is not using the correct language.
I use this code to set the language in a config file, included in ALL files.

```
$language = "ES_AR.utf8";  //this is the locale name on the linux machine.
putenv("LANG=$language");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);
$domain = 'messages';
bindtextdomain($domain, APP_PATH . "/locale");
textdomain($domain);
```

As I said it works good.

I put this code at the top of the cron file, and the problem persists.

So the question is, is there something I can do to force a language when running the cron file from shell??

Thanks!!!

Comment: You may use [PHP-I18N](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-I18N) and just initialize gettext with an auto-detected language or custom selection.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a fix....

I need to put:

```
putenv("LANGUAGE=");
```

just before I set the locale.

I found the answer here: [Gettext not working through php-cli, but works in php-apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220683/gettext-not-working-through-php-cli-but-works-in-php-apache?rq=1)

Do not think I did not search before, I did, but that question is using other words!

I hope it helps someone!!!